Probability That a Given Modulus of Uniformly Distributed Integer Exceeds the Sum Moduli of Others
I've  been thinking of  an interesting probability problem involving a set of independent and identically distributed (iid) random variables, and I'm seeking some hints or solutions. The problem as follows:
Consider a sequence of $n$ iid random variables, $X_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, each distributed uniformly over the integers in the interval $[-n,n]$. I am interested in finding the probability that the first random variable, $X_1$, is greater than the sum of all the other random variables in the sequence combined, plus one. That is :
\begin{equation}
P\left(|X_1| > 1 + \sum_{i=2}^{n} |X_i|\right)
\end{equation}.
Here is  a simulation of the values of probabilities:

Any suggestios/hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

PS: The random variables $X_i$ are uniformly distributed over $[-n, n]$, hence the probability distribution function (pdf) of each $X_i$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
P(X_i = x) = \frac{1}{2n+1}, \quad \text{for } x \in \{-n, -n+1, \ldots, n\}
\end{equation}

Why make them signed integers, only to consider just their absolute values?  From the title I would have expected to see the absolute values outside the sum, not on the inside.

@ErickWong,i edited the title

The probability is going to be vanishingly small for large $n$.  Since the RHS needs to be $\le n$ in order for the event to occur, we can model it by the simpler problem "What's the probability that $n-1$ integers uniformly chosen from $[0,n]$ add up to $<n$?".  This is easily seen to be exactly $C(2n-2, n-1) / (n+1)^{n-1}$, which is less than $(2/(n+1))^{n-1}$, certainly less than $O(1/n!)$.

Aesthetically, I still don't really understand why the distribution is uniform over signed integers when sign plays no role in the question (e.g. why not make them uniform unsigned integers).  Can you provide some background motivation for why this particular question is interesting?
